# How to solve the org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run this program:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class HtmlDriver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
     // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
     // not the implementation.
  WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

      // And now use this to visit Google
      driver.get("http://www.stumbleupon.com/home/");

      // Find the text input element by its name
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

      // Enter something to search for
      element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

      // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
      element.submit();

      // Check the title of the page
      System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getPageSource());
 }
}
```

And I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: q
>      System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.27-7-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_12'
>      Driver info: driver.version: HtmlDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByName(HtmlUnitDriver.java:651)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$4.findElement(By.java:148)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1133)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
>       at  org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:869)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1130)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:330)
>       at com.webdrivertest.HtmlDriver.main(HtmlDriver.java:20)

Please help me out in resolving it.

Comment: I suggest using Selenium IDE. That way you can 'drive' through the pages you want, and then format the code to the language that you require.

Comment: Any one found answer for this question? I am googling from yesterday but no one provided a solution for this. I am wondering is there any solution available for this problem?

Comment: HtmlUnitDriver is a is bad in executing JS. If the targeted webpage uses a lot os JS or even AJAX HtmlUnitDriver it is no option. The great thing about selenium web drivers is, that you can run the same code with real browsers, as mentioned in other answers...

Answer (score 5):

There's no element with name="q" on that page, hence, NoSuchElementException.  You took the example from google and changed the site it goes to, but it's still looking for a google search box on the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        try {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // And now use this to visit Google
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");

            // Find the text input element by its name
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

            // Enter something to search for
            element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

            // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
            element.submit();

            // Check the title of the page
            System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When change the HtmlUnitDriver to FirefoxDriver, it is work!

Answer (score 1):

Using the example from the Selenium site, exactly as it is, the test fails with the same `NoSuchElementException`. It fails also when instantiated with browser emulation such as `BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3`.

Does the HtmlUnitDriver work at all?
Is there a need to configure it in some way first?

**Update:** I'm sitting behind a proxy and unlike the drivers that use real browsers, this driver doesn't know about the proxy. It must be manually configured in the test case with a call to:

```
HtmlUnitDriver.setProxy(host, port);
```

I haven't yet figured out how to configure it with username and password for those proxies that require authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the `WebDriver` to use Firefox explicitly:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use Normal `WebElement` For Submit

Instead you can try

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.id("formid")); //Id of FORM Tag
form.submit();
```